# Shallow copy vs deep copy issue iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, clone, deep-copy, nscopying

I am facing issue to clone an object in swift 3. I want to duplicate/clone an object then want to modify it's value so that modification doesn't reflect on the actual object. Here is what I did.

```
let patientInformation = PatientInformationController.shared().pateintInformation.copy() as! PateintInformation

patientInformation.firstName = "Some Name"
```

The above line actually not just modifying the local copy but also affecting the actual PatientInformationController.shared().pateintInformation.firstName 
The PateintInformation conforms to NSCopying protocol.

I have checked memory addresses for both objects (actual and copy), they are different.

In PatientInformation class:

```
required public init(instance: PateintInformation) {
    self.firstName = instance.firstName
}

public func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any { 
    return PateintInformation(instance: self) 
}
```

Comment: If `PatientInformationController.shared().pateintInformation` and `patientInformation` truly reference two difference object instances then setting `firstName` of `patientInformation` can't be also changing the `firstName` of `PatientInformationController.shared().pateintInformation`.

Comment: How is the copy working? What's your code? Did you check the adress of `firstName` property for each one?

Comment: I have implemented copyWithZone: of NSCopying protocol.

Comment: @A.Sen firstName is a String type?

Comment: @EugeneLaminskiy Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You've incorrectly implemented conformance of class to NSCopying protocol. You have same references in copy and in object, that's why changes happens. You can look [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-copy-objects-in-swift-using-copy) how to do it.

Comment: And you know this how? The OP has not posted any useful code to make this answer yet.

Comment: This is the code I have used in PatientInformation class: public func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any
    {
        return PateintInformation(instance: self)
    }

Comment: It's obvious for me. If after copy() both copy and object are changes, then copy implemented not correctly.

Comment: @A.Sen post a constructor please

Comment: @EugeneLaminskiy How should I assign then? Below is how my constructor look like: required public init(instance: PateintInformation) {
 self.firstName = instance.firstName
}

Comment: @A.Sen You need to edit your question with relevant code. Don't post it in comments.

Comment: @rmaddy Edited.

Comment: @A.Sen Please, connect to chat room "Shallow copy vs deep copy issue iOS Swift" we will discuss this issue

Comment: @EugeneLaminskiy I cannot join to the chat room. My account is not yet eligible for that.